# Text Wrapping differences in IE7, IE8, and FF

Tags: css, cross-browser

When I have this `<table>` below, the text wraps as needed in FF and IE8, but when I run this in compatibility mode or IE7 the text does not wrap and the width of the previous is basically ignored. Any way to get around this? Here is a simplified example.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:125px">
      hi
      </td>
      <td>bye</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      line of text that will equal more than the above width
      </td>
     <td>bye</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Any reason you can't also set the width on the second row, first cell?

Comment: No, there's definitely no reason I couldn't do that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="width:125px">
      hi
      </td>
      <td>bye</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td  style="width:125px">
      line of text that will equal more than the above width
      </td>
     <td>bye</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```